# Why is there a separation between my content and browser screen end?

Tags: html, css

There's a small gap between all my content on my website and the end of the browser window, and I can't figure out why it's there. This is what my CSS code looks like for my Hero Image.

And this is my HTML for that image, as well as for a banner underneath the image with which I have the same separation problem.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.full-width-banner {
  position: auto;
  background-color: #466995;
  padding: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  text-height: 40px;
  width: 73%;
  overflow: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sands serif;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-banner">
  <h2> &ldquo;Change will not come if we wait for some other person or some other time. We are the ones we&rsquo;ve been waiting for. We are the change that we seek.&rdquo; </h2>
  <p>Barack Obama<p>
</div>
```

This is a picture of what that creates, an empty gap between the image and the end of the browser page on the left side. The picture is supposed to completely cover its portion of the browser with no border on either side. [image: The hero image of the website separated from the browser end]

I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you removed the `margin` and `padding` from the `body` and `html` tags. There is not enough code here for us to troubleshoot, since we cannot replicate what you see. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you add `margin: 0;` to `body` element?

Comment: Please modify that snippet so it shows your problem. I removed a truncated element tag at the start, so put that back in and complete it if it's important.

Comment: The picture you've supplied and the code do not match. Please edit the question to give us the code that picture is referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your browser will add a few px of margin or/and padding to your body, just make sure to cleanse that at the beginning of your CSS like so:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class="full-width-banner" src="https://ijnet.org/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_node/public/story/2020-07/cooper-baumgartner-J9QvzfkQM44-unsplash.jpg?h=8c0e36cd&itok=F6g99LH1">
```

Comment: If this is actually the problem there are probably 50 duplicates on this site. You should flag for those instead of repeating this answer.